# Questions fading into oblivion rather quickly?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

Previously, it used to be that if you asked a question on Stack Overflow and didn't immediately get a good answer, you could leave the site and check back within 2-5 days, and chances were that you would've received more answers. I think this might've been accomplished by showing randomly selected questions from a user's favorite tags on the homepage, as opposed to just the newquest questions.

However, if I ask a question now, the only views/answers I receive are within the first hour, if I don't get a good reply within the first hour, it basically means I wouldn't get any other replies. I've also been noticing fewer views and more unanswered questions on other people's profiles than before.

Now it seems like the only way to receive an answer after the first 1-2 hours is to put a bounty on that question.

Has anyone else also noticed this? Has this been caused by an update in the last couple of months/year?

Comment: Well, the experts are moving to more specific sites on StackExchange. Therefore the signal/noise ratio is getting worse, resulting in less people going through the unanswered questions.

Comment: Any data to back up the response time claims?  (You could go through your question history and plot it out)

Comment: If this is indeed happening (I haven't seen any data confirming it), I can only assume it's because of the sheer *volume* of questions that get asked. Your question gets quickly pushed down to page 5, if not page 10, after only a few hours. I suspect most people don't get that far when they sit down to start answering questions.

Comment: I agree with Cody Gray... If I have time to answer some questions, I start with the first unanswered on the first page. As soon as I have this answered, there are already 10 other new unanswered questions on the first page for the same tag. So I'm always answering the questions from the first page. Only very rarely I especially search for questions that are old, (have a lot of upvotes) and are unanswered.

Comment: @jzd It has been my general experience, I've asked almost 400 questions on SO and have noticed it getting harder to get answers. @Let_Me_Be @Cody I think if something could be done to randomly bring forward old questions to the homepage, that could solve this issue.

Comment: @Click, could it possibly that your questions are getting harder and harder as you continue to learn?

Comment: @jzd Its not that I don't still get answers, its that the only answers I seem to get now are within the first 60-100 mins, whereas previously I'd get answers even 2-3 days later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/

The volume of questions is enormous compared to what it used to be, and there are sometimes quality problems -- which is why we've gotten much stricter about rejecting askers (and, rarely, answerers) when the quality isn't there.

- https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/
- https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/how-to-say-thanks-in-an-answer/

Comment: Would be really cool if the questions could still be rotated randomly so they don't go into oblivion after the first hour or so. E.g randomly pick a question with a low number of answers (1-2) asked in the last month, and show it.